# SOQL to get all tasks of opportunities for an account

Tags: soql

I am still new to Salesforce and haven't quite wrapped my head around SOQL queries yet. I still tend to think more in terms of SQL. 
Anyway, I am trying to write a statement that gives me all "Call Tasks" that are attached to all Opportunities of an Account.

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opporunity, (SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE Type="Call") FROM Account
```

Any ideas in how to make this work?
Tia.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way:

```
select Id, Subject
from Task
where WhatId in (select Id from Opportunity where AccountId = :accountId)
and Type = 'Call'
order by Subject
```

The [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) documentation is well worth reading.

**PS**

On the subject of where to get the Account ID, probably the simplest way in a controller extension is this, though in the "new" case there won't be an ID hence the alternate logic:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    private Id accountId;
    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        accountId = sc.getId();
    }
    ...
    public Task[] getTasks() {
        if (accountId != null) {
            return [
                    select Id, Subject
                    from Task
                    where WhatId in (select Id from Opportunity where AccountId = :accountId)
                    and Type = 'Call'
                    order by Subject
                    ];
        } else {
            return new Task[] {};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work but you need to add the additional WHERE clause of Type = "Call"

Comment: @JesseAltman Woops missed that thanks. Will add it.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to show the results on a Visualforce page, and now I am wondering whether I need to create a controller extension for the page, as I cannot see anywhere to edit the standard controller.

Comment: @Lily Yes controller extensions are for exactly this purpose, where you have some custom logic to use in addition to the custom controller. The extension can be as small as a few lines of code.

Comment: @KeithC - I am not sure where the accountID variable comes from?

Comment: @Lily Your question said "of an Account" so accountId is just representing a variable that you have the Account ID set in. Where it comes from depends on where you are running this code, with two common cases being from a controller or trigger. You'll have to add more information to the question or perhaps better post a different question about that.

Comment: @KeithC I am running it from a visualforce page controller which is the standard controller of Account, and I was thinking of getting it this way:  `System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id'))` unfortunately I get an error when I do it like that...

Comment: @Lily See the PS. Your method should also work though.

Comment: @KeithC - That looks interesting. I will try that. However, it's a different structure to what I am used to when using a Visualforce page. Could you please explain how I am now able to show all the tasks in a table?

Comment: @Lily Visualforce tables are well documented. Give it a go and if you are stuck after say a day of trying ask a new question.

Comment: @KeithC - yes, I know how to do the VF tables, but the problem is that usually I can write something like `{!calls.Subject}` to display the subject. In the controller above, I don't end up with a list, so I am not sure how I can access the variables from my v/f page. Does that question make sense?

Comment: In Visualforce you reference `tasks` and that causes `getTasks` to be called. Arrays and lists are interchangeable, so the return value `Task[]` is the same as the return type `List<Task>`.